# Twilio and cakephp Authentication Error - No credentials provided

Tags: cakephp, twilio

Hi I am using the following Twilio plugin for cakephp https://github.com/manleys/Twilio-Plugin-CakePHP-2.0

however I am having issues getting it to work. After adding my app id and api key to the config/twilio.php file I keep getting the error  "Authentication Error - No credentials provided"

not sure why I am having the issue. My controller function is:

```
    public function sendsms() {

$to = $this->Auth->user('phone');
$message = $this->Auth->user('name');

$this->Twilio->sendSingleSms($to, $message);
$this->redirect->referer();

}
```

any help would be well appreciated

Comment: Have you added your Account SID and Auth Token to the plugin config?

Comment: Yes I did, think there may be an issue with the plugin